# EXTJS4 XML Store - Displaying

Tags: javascript, xml, extjs, extjs4

I have a Perl script which returns an XML formatted SOAP request to my EXTJS4. Here is the code that loads and displays the XML (this is my first go at EXTJS):

```
Ext.onReady(function() {  
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});

    Ext.define('accounts', {     
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'origin', type: 'string'}
            ]
    }); 

    var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'accounts',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'cgi-bin/runPerl.pl',
            reader: {
                type: 'xml',
                root: 'soap:Body'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    });

     myStore.on('load', function(store, records, options) {

        var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl for="Accounts">',
            '<h1>{values.data.name}</h1>',
            '<h1>{values.data.origin}</h1>',
            '</tpl>'
        );

        //tpl.append(Ext.get("output"), store.getRange());

    });
```

Here is the XML:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<ns2:getAccountsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://services.nms.nimsoft.com/">
<Accounts>
<accountId>1</accountId>
<address></address>
<city></city>
<country></country>
<creationDate>2012-04-11T00:00:00+01:00</creationDate>
<description></description>
<fax></fax>
<name>Network</name>
<origin>Support_4</origin>
<phone></phone>
<postalCode></postalCode>
<state></state>
<webSite></webSite>
</Accounts>
</ns2:getAccountsResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Firebug displays the following:

```
Ext.DomQuery.pseudos[name] is not a function
[Break On This Error]
```

return Ext.DomQuery.pseudos[name](cs, value);

I have narrowed this down to the tpl section but for the life of me cannot understand the error I am getting.

Can anyone offer advise please? Thanks!

Comment: why don't you try to debug `records` there in the load handler to see what's inside?

Comment: any pointers on that? Like I say am quite new to this. @sha

Comment: before you do `tpl = `, add line `console.log(records)`. This way you will see array of records in your debug console. There you can browse through them and see their fields and everything else. May be it will give you some hints.

Comment: @sha Thanks for the reply but I dont think the code even gets that far. Nothing is shown.

I see in firbug the XML is returned but I dont think my sytax is right for loading it into the store some how.

If I say the root is 'soap:Body' I the error above.

If i say 'Accounts' - Path is undefined - 'var paths = path.split(","),'

Comment: See my answer. According to the docs - you need to specify 'record' property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your reader definition as:

```
reader: {
    type: 'xml',
    // root: 'soap:Body',
    record: 'Accounts'
}
```

Comment: your amazing thank your the help, well on my way to my first EXTJS app now and loving the frameworks so far!